# How do I convert json into a dataframe making a default row into a new columns based on delimiter?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am working in Colab with the following line of code:

json line:

```
'company_size': [51, 200]
```

python code:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = response.json()
result = pd.json_normalize(data, 'company_size')
result
```

output:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 51 |
| 1 | 200 |

What I want is the info inside the box brackets on the json line to be displayed into two different columns named "Size Min" and "Size Max" respectively.

*Desired Output*:

|  | Size Min | Size Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 51 | 200 |

I am very new to coding, and I couldn't find a proper solution for this. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose your column 0 and then rename the columns accordingly

```
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 data = response.json()
 result = pd.json_normalize(data, 'company_size').T
 result.columns = ['Size Min','Size Max']
 result
```